# Term for homophones that have opposite meanings?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for homophones that have opposite meanings to each other?

For instance, **Whole** vs **Hole**

Also, are there any more examples of such words?

Comment: Do you mean antonymic homophones like *raze* and *raise*, or do you mean antonymic homonyms like *table* and *table*?

Comment: More like *raze* and *raise*

Comment: It's an antonym... It's a homophone... It's an antonymic homophone! (or homophonic antonym, perhaps? Either way, I doubt there's a special term for them.) As for another example, there's _douse_ and _dowse_ - I wouldn't call those true antonyms, but that may be as close as you'll find, outside of _raise_ and _raze_.

Comment: I also think it is a huge stretch to say _hole_ and _whole_ have opposite meanings.

Comment: There's [auto-antonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym) (and *contranym/contronym*) for single words which are their own antonym, but I think it's unlikely there would be a term for **homophonic pairs** which are antonyms. Anyway, I don't think *hole/whole* would really qualify, and asking for "any more examples" isn't a constructive question either.